# How to find a point is located inside a line or polygon

Tags: android

I found a point is located inside a Circle using following method.

- Distance between a point and circle center <= circle radius means the point is inside circle.

But I need to find

- The point is located in a line
- The point is located in a polygon

Normally polyline has array of coordinates,if i check with all points in-between points will miss while calculating.

**Update:**

I used [github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point](http://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point) to find the point is located in a polygon. But it is 2D normal plane. But I need to find a point inside a Polygon calculation on spheroid.How to do this?

Comment: I used a jar file for polygon in http://geospatialmethods.org/spheres/. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q2: search for "point in polygon strategies", from graphic gems.
Point in Polygon also works if the coordinates are longitude (x), latitude (y).
At least the algo that count for line crossings, which mostly are the one implemented.
Of course if the polygn crosses the datum limit (by ship or plane) or is located at the polar region, then this does not work with the simple apporach.

q1: point line: in school you learned that (abs(normal distance to line) < epsilon)
but what you need is `distance to line segment`. (not line which has infinity length).

For this task you have to transfrom to cartestioan coordinates first.

Comment: as i said, then use distance to line segment. search on internet

Comment: I used https://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point to find the point is located in a polygon

Comment: github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point provides normal polygon,but i need to convert this same method to calculate gepgraphical coordinates,because of spheroid of earth shape.

Comment: No, point in polygon works also if the coordinates are lat,lon; because the algorithm checks for line crossings. For distanceToLineSegent you need to transform first, but not for pointInside()

Comment: I used a jar file for polygon in geospatialmethods.org/spheres. I think it works fine.